# convert Thu Sep 02 16:29:11 UTC 2021 to timestamp in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to convert varchar `Thu Sep 02 16:29:11 UTC 2021`  to the timestamp in the snowflake database?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('Thu Sep 02 16:29:11 UTC 2021', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS UTC YYYY');
```

For reference, here is a link to the documentation on the "parts".

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html